# How to parse json string to ArrayList<NameValuePair>

Tags: java, json, gson

I am new to json and need to send some data from server to client. I receive data in client as a json string but need to convert it to `ArrayList<NameValuePair>`.
I have tried:

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<NameValuePair>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<NameValuePair> arrayList = new Gson().fromJson(response, type);
```

But I it throws exception, so I need a better method to do it. I hope my situation is clear.  All valid answers will be appreciated.

Comment: `09-12 11:31:20.992: W/System.err(2985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
`

Comment: please post an example of your json string.

Comment: i got another method,m requiremnt is over thanks,anyways

Answer (score 3):

I think the below code is helpful for you.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>>() {}.getType();
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Never thought `BasicNameValuePair` would be the answer to it.